# Thumbnail preview for my pdf files in drupal 7

Tags: content-management-system, drupal-7, thumbnails, html

How to create book cover thumbnails in drupal 7? Let us say I am going to search all IT books, the result should be in grid format with book cover along with the name of the book and the author. Then if one of the books click, it will view the contents of the book. Like those in amazon or other books related website. How to achieve this one? Is there any module to do this?